# How to send events in a frame model?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

We have a frame model and lots of components in it. On nearly each frame `Update()` function of nearly each component is called by Frame model controller (say Unity3d and all that happens, takes place in one thread). We have components that are `"Targets"` that change some of there properties (for example position) and want to tall other components - `"Consumers"` (for example missiles) about that fact.

If we use normal C# event model and "raise" events from `"Targets"` we will get really long `Update` call. One that can freeze all our frame based app. So we can not really use C# events as much as we would like.

What have we done: for each `"Consumer"` component we subscribe to `"Targets"` events with actions that push all new data into a List and on `"Component"` Update call we iterate thru list of new data and make our update.

So my question is: is there a way to generealise such approach (say if we have not only want targets to affect our missiles but also `"winds"` with there own incoming data (for example direction and temprature)) to make code look nice?

Is ther any more correct way of sending events in frame model?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you are using a modified observer pattern right now. `Targets` are then the *subjects* to observe for changes or publishers. `Consumer` is the *Observer* interface declaring the notify method, the subscribers. If you now extract the observer functionality into a separate class, other classes can benefit from it:

```
// info to send to all active missiles
public class MissileInfoMessage { }

// all missile classes should implement:
public interface MissileInfoSubscriber {
    void Notify (MissileInfoMessage msg);
}

public class MissileInfoBroker {
    List<MissileInfoSubscriber> missileInfoSubscribers;
    // targets, winds, airplanes calls this to get all missiles notified
    public void NotifyMissiles (MissileInfoMessage msg) {
        foreach (MissileInfoSubscriber missile in missileInfoSubscribers) {
            missile.Notify (msg);
        }
    }
    // missiles register when they got fired
    public void Register (MissileInfoSubscriber s) {
        missileInfoSubscribers.Add (s);
    }
    // and deregister if their job is done
    public void Unregister (MissileInfoSubscriber s) {
        missileInfoSubscribers.Remove (s);
    }
}
```